# Schedule Full Backups

Tags: sql-server-2014

Quick question. I'm using Ola's solution and with the full backup job for user databases, is there any issue scheduling these at the same time? I saw another thread on here that mentioned that it will just backup each DB one after the other but wanted to confirm?
Thanks!

Comment: At the same time *as what*? Are you running multiple backup jobs, each calling Ola's script with different parameters? Or running a job that performs backups a different way? With the right params, Ola's backup script is designed to walk through and backup each database one at a time, so I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the things you're scheduling at the same time are. I would generally recommend against running a back up and a job that (for instance) moves data around, like Ola's index maintenance job, at the same time. Please clarify what the things you want to schedule at the same time are.

Comment: Let me clarify. I'm looking at the full backup job that is created by his script for the USER_DATABASES.  If I run this job, it will go through and backup each user database. I'm just wondering if it's ok to run it as is. I'm assuming it is since that is one of the options to run it but wanted to confirm.  So for example, I have 4 user databases. I can run this single job and back up all 4 of them. I'm wondering if this is ok or should I create 4 separate jobs and schedule them at different times, like one after the other based on how long each backup takes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this command taken from [ola's website](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) it will backup all your user database one by one, if that is what you are asking. It will create a sub-folder under `c:\backup\` for each database with its name. Each backup file will have server name, database name, date and timestamp.

```
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@Directory = 'C:\Backup',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Verify = 'Y',
@Compress = 'Y',
@CheckSum = 'Y',
@CleanupTime = 24
```

If you need these same databases to backup in parallel you will need to create 4 jobs with database name passed to `@Databases` parameter and schedule at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering how this would get processed when using a single job. I do see the DB's backing up in the log one after the other as you said. I just wanted to get some feedback on best practices. In the past the full databases backups were staggered at different times. It sounds like if I set these up to run in parallel like you mentioned, the backups would finish faster?

Comment: As I said it will do one after another. Yes you can have multiple job and run in parallel but you need to be careful with your resources. Best option is to test and decide.